# Jenkins Setup Issue

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

I have done the Jenkins Setup to clone solution from Github Repo and trigger the build and solution should run on multiple browsers in parallel (I'm using ANT build).

But when I'm trying to run scripts, its triggering the build but unable to clone solution on VM, throwing below error

```
Started by upstream project "HippoAutomationTests" build number 12
originally caused by:
 Started by user Andy Williams
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox
using credential b89b0ace-6852-43d4-83a7-83f3ba77a290
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket.org/kohler_source/hippoautomationtests.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/kohler_source/hippoautomationtests.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket Credentials
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/kohler_source/hippoautomationtests.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Checking out Revision 104215052b7b4ae548eb2a4782bd9292bc93b95a (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 104215052b7b4ae548eb2a4782bd9292bc93b95a
Commit message: "Updating the solution"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 104215052b7b4ae548eb2a4782bd9292bc93b95a # timeout=10
[Firefox] $ /x01/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/Ant_Installation/bin/ant -file build.xml -DGroup=HippoIndia -Dbrowser=Firefox -DURL=http://plumbingindia.kohler.acct.us.onehippo.com/ -DrealTimeReport=true -DrunParallel=methods -Dselenium.capture.path=/Test/build/test-output/new -Dtest.url=http://plumbingindia.kohler.acct.us.onehippo.com/ -DuseVideoCapture=false -DbuildName=Test -DdbMode=false -Dselenium.timeout=60000 -DlocalExecution=true -DthreadCount=1 -Dtest.browser=Firefox -Dpackages=com.tests.* -Dtest.browser.version=11.0 -DretryCount=0 -Dselenium.port=4444 -DdbUrl=localhost:3306/isaf -DshowVideosOnPass=false -DdataProviderThreadCount=20 -Dgroups=HippoIndia -DuseProxy=false -DdbUser=isaf_user -Dselenium.host=localhost -DdbPass=isaf@123 -DreportType=iwafreport build.config run.test
Buildfile: /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/build.xml

build.config:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/Test/build

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/Test/build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/Test/build/test-classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/Test/build/test-output

compile:
    [javac] /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/build.xml:99: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 18 source files to /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/Test/build/test-classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

run.test:
     [java] Error occurred during initialization of VM
     [java] Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/lib\aspectjweaver.jar
     [java] agent library failed to init: instrument
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/Test/build/test-output/IwafReport to /x01/jenkins/jobs/HippoAutomationTests/configurations/axis-browser/Firefox/htmlreports/HTML_20Report
ERROR: Specified HTML directory '/x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/Test/build/test-output/IwafReport' does not exist.
Build step 'Publish HTML reports' changed build result to FAILURE
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
testng-results.xml was last modified before this build started. Ignoring it.
testng-results.xml was last modified before this build started. Ignoring it.
Saving reports...
Found matching files but did not find any TestNG results.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please provide some suggestion to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `aspectjweaver.jar` JAR is missing on your build environment as per the error message:

> [java] Error occurred during initialization of VM [java] Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /x01/builds/workspace/HippoAutomationTests/browser/Firefox/lib\aspectjweaver.jar
>
> [java] agent library failed to init: instrument
>
> [java] Java Result: 1

Ensure that this JAR is present and don't use `\` as a path delimiter. It should be `lib/aspectjweaver.jar` just like rest of the path.